# Python syntax error for using colon incorrectly?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

what's wrong with the syntax here? i'm getting an error pointing at the colon for search_name. thanks!

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```
result = pd.DataFrame()


def get_player_stats(search_name: str = None, real_name: str = None, player_soup: BeautifulSoup = None) -> DataFrame:
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.6 i believe ```[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin]```

Comment: Use `python --version` to find out which version you're running.

Comment: oh, it looks like it's python 2.7.16

Comment: Type hints were added in Python 3.5.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by type hints and all that but i actually have 3.7 downloaded so i'm not sure what the issue would be